# clipboard not copying newline character

Tags: android, email, newline, clipboard, copy-paste

I am new to Android development.

I am trying to copy the text from the email body into the clipboard and pasting it into my application, but the clipboard does not recognize the new line character.

Any suggestions on how to copy with the newline character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess.

If you are pasting it into an `EditText`, which I assume you are, you may need to set `android:singleLine` to **false**

Comment: @kanchan that is the same thing